# When booking on Indian Railways, can you combine quota tickets with non-quota ones on a single booking?

Tags: bookings, indian-railways

A booking status shows `RL/WL10`, but `2 available` under the Sr. Citizen quota.

Would a booking for two Senior Citizens and one Adult, show confirmation against 2 Sr. citizens and waitlist against 1 adult, if booked under a single PNR?

Comment: What's the downvotes for?

Comment: One could never say that. In an ideal scenario yes, the tickets for the two senior citizens will be confirmed but it depends on the number of people who are booking. In a country like India, its most probably you might not confirmed tickets as there are others(senior citizens) who might book before you.

Comment: It should work that way for a ticket booked at the counter; the person operating the counter should be able to allocate the appropriate quota(s) for different persons even under a single PNR. Not sure how it works if you book online (IRCTC) as there is an option of choosing only one type of quota at the beginning of the booking and Sr. Citizen quota is not one of the options. I am afraid checking at a counter is the best option.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that you can combine these if you book at the counter with a Railways agent, not sure if the online website has the option though.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: NO

Long answer: The other answer is factually WRONG, I am sorry but you cannot combine senior citizen (or for most part) any quota with another ticket, the funny thing about senior citizen quota is you cannot even avail it when two senior citizens travel together, the definition of this quota is something to mean senior citizens travelling without support, so the answer is actually NO for your specific quota, I am not 100% sure of other quotas but many other quota tickets cannot be combined with open reservation.

An official confirmation is in this [link](http://www.indianrailways.gov.in/railwayboard/uploads/directorate/traffic_comm/pdf/Facility_Sr_Citizen.pdf) this clearly says

"When travelling alone" for multiple quotas

Answer (score 2):

Yes(Partially), If you would get the ticket under single PNR, your ticket would be considered  partial confirmed ticket instead of confirmed ticket till all tickets get confirmed.And yes, you can travel on the ticket as well,even if you have e-ticket since your name will appear in reservation chart.

> Name of the passengers whose names are partly confirmed/partly
>   waitlist or partly RAC/partly waitlist, their names shall appear in
>   charts including the waitlist passengers.

[Source](https://www.services.irctc.co.in/beta_htmls/Waitlisted_E-Ticket.html)

Comment: The rule that you quoted is actually primarily for confirmation / boarding the train rather than booking